# Magnetic force between two cylinders/disks

Tags: magnetic-fields

Where can I find a formula to calculate the magnetic force two cylindrical/disk magnets exert on each other that have their axes aligned (there is no lateral displacement). I found formulas in papers (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S030488530900746X?via%3Dihub) and on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets) where the distance between the said magnets is large.

I am looking for forces over small distances. There are websites that do that for you such as this one (https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.repel.asp) but they don't publish formulas. I am happy to work with an approximation too. In case there are no approximations, what advice do you have for me

Comment: actually it is easy for long distances because you can treat them as dipole and you have to do calculations regarding interaction of dipoles

Comment: For this you have to first calculate magnetic field due to a ring on any point in the plane

Comment: and then calculate force by integration which i suppose requires computer